# New Guitar Strings Buzzing

Tags: strings, acoustic-guitar, semi-acoustic-guitar, buzz

I bought new D'Addario 12 gauge Strings got my Fender CD 100 Acoustic Guitar.
The E,A,D Strings seem to be buzzing a lot. Is that normal for new strings?

Comment: What was the gauge of the previous strings?

Comment: I assume them they were 11s or 12s only .... not sure. they were the defaults you get with CD100

Comment: Even though the difference in gauge between 11s and 12s is just .01 on the high E.  On the low end the sets could vary as much as .05 to .08   This could be the cause of the buzz.  Not only because of the different size, but the different tension of the strings.

Comment: So is that normal?

Comment: Yes, but the guitar should be able to handle a small range of different gauges without dramatically altering the setup.  My guess is you'll be able to fix the buzz with a small tweak to the action or truss rod.

Answer (score 2):

It is not normal for new strings. If your old strings didn't buzz, then your new strings may have lighter gauge and therefore the guitar fretboard is too flat. You may need to adjust the truss rod, replace the bridge saddle or get a new heavier gauge set of strings.

By the way - do not wait for the strings to get rusty in order to change them. If at all possible, replace the strings at least once a year or even better once in every 6 months. Strings lose their quality very fast due to stretching, fat/sweat from your fingers and dust. You simply will not get the most from your guitar with old strings.

Comment: Hello -- welcome to Music.SE! On this site, please avoid making multiple posts as if this were a forum. Instead, you should edit your existing answer to add information. I'll merge your two answers now.

Comment: Hello and thanks:) sorry - i didn't quite understand the specifics of posting here at first. Will know better now:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it has been tuned correctly, it is not normal. The old strings were probably 11s or maybe 12s, so there should be no problems if there weren't previously.Do they buzz open, on specific frets, maybe there is another problem with the guitar that has manifested itself when the strings were changed. Were they changed for a particular reason ? Like did one break, were they old, did you not like the sound/feel of the originals? More info. please. How old is the guitar, is it still under warranty ?

Comment: YEs, They do buzz when open.
They were changed as the strings were rusted.
It is few months old but I am in India and not sure if the warranty is valid here ...

Comment: As ecline6 says, action or truss rod. Look along the strings and see if the neck is fairly straight, with the distance between strings and neck roughly the same from bridge to nut. If there is a big difference, or the strings look closer near the middle, then loosen the truss rod by 1/4 turn, check and repeat until the buzz goes. It's a gentle operation that really should be done by someone who knows . If the bridge is too low, again it's a tricky mod, and needs an expert, unless the bridge is adjustable with 2 screws, which I doubt.